# Automating the daily Monitoring

Tags: logging, automation, monitoring

In my day to day tasks I monitor logs on number of windows 2012 R2 servers which are generated by different services run on these servers. I manually monitor many log/text files which is hectic and time consuming.

I am seeking suggestions (technical as well process oriented) on automating this task, please consider the fact that these services run on different severs and not on a single server, sometimes switches from one server to another.

Please suggest me what kind of application I need to write (if i need to..) in which technology or what scripting can achieve this.

I heard about distributed applications, Do I need to develop one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you start learning Python. Python is a vastly used language for automation. For communication with other services/applications you should look into Python modules (libraries) `flask` and `requests` for REST API's. For SOAP you could use `suds` or `zeep`. Save the exported logs into a DB like `MySQL` and iterate over your dB entries with either `Regex` (regular expressions) or go the right way directly and familiarize with NLP (Natural Language Processing) using `NLTK` and `PyEnchant`.

The possitive aspect of python is that you don't need to really understand the programming language since the majority of methods used in those modules are selfexplanatory, which allows very fast development.

I'd recommend starting with 2.7 instead of 3.X since most tutorials for beginners are written in 2.X